# How to solve "unable to test federation connectivity. Cannot locate Identity Provider." in openAM?

Tags: openam

I am using openAM 11 on windows 7 professional 64-bit,  jdk-1.7.0_45 and tomcat 7.0.53.
And I have configured IDP and SP on seperate terminals,but when I try to test federation connectivity,I get this eror "Unable to test federation connectivity. Cannot locate Identity Provider, ."

Comment: Set debug level to message for OpenAM and have a look into "Federation" debug log. You most likely have some issue with your SAML Metadata.

Comment: @Bernhard I am using saml2/jsp/exportmetadata.jsp for both IDP and SP. Can that be a problem ?

Comment: You are just running into https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-3461 , you should contact ForgeRock support (if you have a subscription), or just patch it yourself.

Comment: @Bernhard: Where do I look for Federation log ? (Sorry but I am a newbie to openAM)

Comment: As Peter already pointed out you need to get the fix for OPENAM-3461

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have never had any success with the "test federation connectivity" function in OpenAM/OpenSSO.

What I have used to test that the federation is up and going is spSSOInit.jsp.
It starts a SAML authentication for the user making a request to it.

```
https://youropenamserver/openam/saml2/jsp/spSSOInit.jsp?metaAlias=<The SP meta alias>&idpEntityID=<The IdP entity id>
```

meta alias and entity id can be found on the configuration page for SP and IDP respectively.

[More info on spSSOInit.jsp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-3748/gghzn/index.html)